# javascript loop for implement a class or css

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with a problem.
I have a timeline with dates, and I want to dynamically add a class or CSS opacity when the date is superior of the current date.

All my data is presented dynamically, but I can't achieve that simple thing.

The future result is to someone who views the timeline see the milestones or steps and if the goal date is bigger than current date so it must be with opacity, to feel that is all on schedule.

Thanks for the help in advance.

This is what I want, see **picture** below:

[image]

This is my code, first of all, I can't get the date of the array :(

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div style="display:inline-block;width:100%;overflow-y:auto;margin-top:1em;">
        <ul class="timeline timeline-horizontal">
            <li class="timeline-item aci-to-change" id="SHOW NUMBER ID">
                <div class="timeline-badge primary">SHOW IMAGE</div>
                <div class="timeline-panel"><div class="timeline-heading"><h4 class="timeline-title">SHOW TITLE</h4>
                        <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>SHOW DATE</small></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-body"><p>SHOW TEXT</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
        //date of today
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) {
          dd = '0' + dd;
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
          mm = '0' + mm;
        }
        today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;
        //console.log(today);

        // other dates in li
        var myStringArray = document.getElementsByClassName("aci-miles-date");
        var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
        //console.log(arrayLength);
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                //console.log(myStringArray[i]);
                var allDates = myStringArray[i].innerText;
                //console.log(allDates);
                //console.log(today);
                for (var i = 0; i < allDates.length; i++) {
                    //console.log(allDates);
                    if (allDates[i].innerText > today){
                        $(".timeline-item").addClass("aci-futureOpacity");
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `if(goalDate > currentDate) opacityAll[i].className = "timeline-item aci-futureOpacity";` ?

Comment: There are no dates in the code you have provided, where do they come from?

Comment: Thanks Mirakurun what you have said is correct but i cant get the goalDate...

Comment: Hi Tom, the date is comming with sql and then replaced in the code.